# mainWindow.skipTaskbar has no effect

Tags: javascript, electron

when I create a window and set the skipTaskbar directly in the configurations, it works:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      webviewTag: true,
      devTools: false
    },
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.ico'),
    skipTaskbar: true
  });
```

But when I try to write like this:

```js
mainWindow.skipTaskbar = true
```

doesn't work, why?

That is, I want that when the application is loaded - it was not on the taskbar, and when loaded - so that it appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `mainWindow.setSkipTaskbar(bool)`